# JavaScript set a timer based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval

I need help with trying to set a timer based on the user input through the value of a `select - option` in html. And then be able to count to 0 from that number. I need help with finding a way to make the value of hours, minutes, seconds to decrement. I tried making it countdown from a certain time that I hard coded, but I need it to countdown from whatever the user input it.

```js
var now = new Date();

var x = setInterval(function () {

 var hours = parseInt(document.getElementById("hours").value);
 var minutes = parseInt(document.getElementById("minutes").value);
 var seconds = parseInt(document.getElementById("seconds").value);

 var hDistance = hours - now.getHours();
 var mDistance = minutes - now.getMinutes();
 var sDistance = seconds - now.getSeconds();

 Math.floor((hDistance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
 Math.floor((mDistance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
 Math.floor((sDistance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

 document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + " : " +
  minutes + " : " + seconds;

}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="timer-display">

 <p id="timer"></p>
</div>

<body>

 <div class="main">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <label for="hours">Hours</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <label for="minutes">Minutes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <label for="seconds">Seconds</label>&nbsp;

  <br>

  <select name="hours" id="hours">
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
   <option value="13">13</option>
   <option value="14">14</option>
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="16">16</option>
   <option value="17">17</option>
   <option value="18">18</option>
   <option value="19">19</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="21">21</option>
   <option value="22">22</option>
   <option value="23">23</option>
  </select>

  <select name="minutes" id="minutes">
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
   <option value="13">13</option>
   <option value="14">14</option>
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="16">16</option>
   <option value="17">17</option>
   <option value="18">18</option>
   <option value="19">19</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="21">21</option>
   <option value="22">22</option>
   <option value="24">24</option>
   <option value="25">25</option>
   <option value="26">26</option>
   <option value="27">27</option>
   <option value="28">28</option>
   <option value="29">29</option>
   <option value="30">30</option>
   <option value="31">31</option>
   <option value="32">32</option>
   <option value="33">33</option>
   <option value="34">34</option>
   <option value="35">35</option>
   <option value="36">36</option>
   <option value="37">37</option>
   <option value="38">38</option>
   <option value="39">39</option>
   <option value="40">40</option>
   <option value="41">41</option>
   <option value="42">42</option>
   <option value="43">43</option>
   <option value="44">44</option>
   <option value="45">45</option>
   <option value="46">46</option>
   <option value="47">47</option>
   <option value="48">48</option>
   <option value="49">49</option>
   <option value="50">50</option>
   <option value="51">51</option>
   <option value="52">52</option>
   <option value="53">53</option>
   <option value="54">54</option>
   <option value="55">55</option>
   <option value="56">56</option>
   <option value="57">57</option>
   <option value="58">58</option>
   <option value="59">59</option>
  </select>

  <select name="seconds" id="seconds">
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
   <option value="13">13</option>
   <option value="14">14</option>
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="16">16</option>
   <option value="17">17</option>
   <option value="18">18</option>
   <option value="19">19</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="21">21</option>
   <option value="22">22</option>
   <option value="24">24</option>
   <option value="25">25</option>
   <option value="26">26</option>
   <option value="27">27</option>
   <option value="28">28</option>
   <option value="29">29</option>
   <option value="30">30</option>
   <option value="31">31</option>
   <option value="32">32</option>
   <option value="33">33</option>
   <option value="34">34</option>
   <option value="35">35</option>
   <option value="36">36</option>
   <option value="37">37</option>
   <option value="38">38</option>
   <option value="39">39</option>
   <option value="40">40</option>
   <option value="41">41</option>
   <option value="42">42</option>
   <option value="43">43</option>
   <option value="44">44</option>
   <option value="45">45</option>
   <option value="46">46</option>
   <option value="47">47</option>
   <option value="48">48</option>
   <option value="49">49</option>
   <option value="50">50</option>
   <option value="51">51</option>
   <option value="52">52</option>
   <option value="53">53</option>
   <option value="54">54</option>
   <option value="55">55</option>
   <option value="56">56</option>
   <option value="57">57</option>
   <option value="58">58</option>
   <option value="59">59</option>
  </select><br>

  <button class="start-timer" id="startTimer">Start Timer</button>


 </div>
```

Comment: Did you get your hard-coded example to work? If so, seems like some valuable code is missing from the example.

Comment: Heres a JSFiddle link for that [link](https://jsfiddle.net/qye1ac3n/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there ^_^ I had some fun getting this working.  Firstly, you do need to attach change listeners to your selects so you can get the values.  Then, you can set up your interval.  Below is the code I used ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/5g3hzbmp/1/) is the fiddle too)

```
var hours = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var interval = null;

document.getElementById('hours').addEventListener('change', e => {
    hours = +e.target.value;
});

document.getElementById('minutes').addEventListener('change', e => {
    minutes = +e.target.value;
});

document.getElementById('seconds').addEventListener('change', e => {
    seconds = +e.target.value;
});

document.getElementById('startTimer').addEventListener('click', () => {
    var timeInSeconds = (hours * 60 * 60) +
        (minutes * 60) +
        seconds;

    var displayTime = () => {
        var displayHours = Math.floor(timeInSeconds / (60 * 60));
        var remainder = timeInSeconds - (displayHours * 60 * 60);
        var displayMinutes = Math.floor(remainder / 60);
        var displaySeconds = remainder - (displayMinutes * 60);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = displayHours + " : " + displayMinutes + " : " + displaySeconds;
    };
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        displayTime();
        timeInSeconds -= 1;
        if (timeInSeconds < 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for something like this.

Comment: @bxndit You're welcome!  Don't forget to accept the answer if it so pleases you :)